# Copy from stdin in Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I'm using jdbc to connect my backend to an OracleDB. Is there a PostgreSQL-like

```
COPY ... FROM STDIN (...)
```

in OracleDB, or something equally quick?

I should be able to insert over 1 Million entries without the requirement of using asynchronous calls - this means for me: as quick as possible :).

Comment: I don't use PostgreSQL, but [from the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-copy.html) it sounds like you might want [external tables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables.html), or maybe SQL\*Loader? Depends where the data is though I suppose... Bulk inserts are maybe a more obvious solution over JDBC but more work, especially if the data is already in a flat file.

Comment: @AlexPoole SQL*Loader seems to promise a quick result. I will test that. The difference between COPY FROM STDIN in Postgre from a normal Bulk insert is that it's quick, due to omiting Triggers and other actions on the inserted bulk.